# ClassCastException: com.sum.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2

Tags: java, gradle, stax

I am trying to use the Woodstox StAX parser in a plugin for Android Studio that I am building in IntelliJ using gradle.

I get the below error when trying to get an instance of an XMLInputFactory2.

```java
XMLInputFactory2 xif = (XMLInputFactory2) XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2
    at com.insidesecure.plugin.structure.CPSettingsConfigurable.apply(CPSettingsConfigurable.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableWrapper.apply(ConfigurableWrapper.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor.apply(ConfigurableEditor.java:317)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsEditor$5.apply(SettingsEditor.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor$2.actionPerformed(ConfigurableEditor.java:65)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:729)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:674)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:373)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:706)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:437)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1682)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1631)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.lambda$show$0(SettingsDialog.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.show(SettingsDialog.java:73)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.showSettingsDialog(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:84)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsAction.perform(ShowSettingsAction.java:54)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsAction.actionPerformed(ShowSettingsAction.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:261)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:278)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:292)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:283)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:282)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:35)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:546)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:729)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:674)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:373)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I have already come across posts with similar issues, but nothing has helped me overcome this problem.

I am aware that this has something to do with how I import the Woodstox dependency. Below is part of my build.gradle, with two attempts of importing woodstox (don't know if fasterxml or codehouse is correct) and mutliple attempts at trying to exclude the classes that could be causing the problem.

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation "org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:5.4.1"
    runtimeOnly 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.10'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.woodstox/woodstox-core
//    compile (group: 'com.fasterxml.woodstox', name: 'woodstox-core', version: '5.2.1') {
//        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
//        exclude group: 'com.sun.xml', module:'internal'
//    }

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api
    compile ('org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.sun.xml', module:'internal'
        exclude group: 'javax.xml.stream', module:'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'stax', module:'stax-api'
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error? What is the correct way to add Woodstox as a dependency in gradle? Thank you.

Comment: Both of those classes are abstract. Is there an implantation class in Woodstock to use?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean by implantation class.

The following uses the javax.xml.stream.* classes and works fine.

` XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance(); 
` XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader( new fileInputStream(configFilePath));

Guides online state that to use Stax2, you need to cast to XMLInputFactory2, XMLStreamReader2, etc...

However, any casting gives the same error. This is because Java seems to be calling com.sun.xml.internal.... instead of javax.xml.stream...

Comment: "implementation" auto correct problem.  That maybe a class loading problem and someone with more knowledge on Woodstock will need to help on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this cast error by using the woodstox osgi InputFactoryProviderImpl instead.

```java
import com.ctc.wstx.osgi.InputFactoryProviderImpl;
import com.ctc.wstx.osgi.OutputFactoryProviderImpl;
import org.codehaus.stax2.XMLEventReader2;
import org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2;
import org.codehaus.stax2.XMLOutputFactory2;

InputFactoryProviderImpl iprovider = new InputFactoryProviderImpl();
OutputFactoryProviderImpl oprovider = new OutputFactoryProviderImpl();

XMLInputFactory2 ifactory = iprovider.createInputFactory();
XMLOutputFactory2 ofactory = oprovider.createOutputFactory();

XMLEventReader2 in = (XMLEventReader2) ifactory.createXMLEventReader(
        new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(filePath)));

XMLEventWriter out = ofactory.createXMLEventWriter(result);
```